# Prevent midi driver from sleeping on MS Surface 4

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winforms, midi

I have a Windows Forms application that reacts to Midi events emanating from a button click on a Midi/USB footswitch. This works great with very little latency on almost all PCs...However on the Microsoft Surface 4 (and probably 5, 6 etc.) tablet, Microsoft appears to put the Midi (or USB) driver to sleep as soon as possible after sound stops playing on the device...immediately after! I'm sure the Surface is doing this to conserve power/battery but it is a deal breaker for my app.

In my app I need to react to the footswitch button click with little to no latency regardless of whether sound is currently playing or not. On the Surface, once the Midi driver is put to sleep there is about a 1 second delay between the user clicking the button on the midi/USB footswitch and the related midi event arriving at my application's code to be processed. This delay is a deal breaker for my app since my app uses the button clicks to trigger music/sound/notes and this latency (actually an outright long 1 second delay) makes playing music impossible.

Given some work I've done in attempting to workaround this issue I believe that this is more likely the midi driver sleeping than the USB driver sleeping. I created some code that sent a bogus Midi message every 1 second to keep the midi driver awake and that worked but I ran into some other issues that resulted in the workaround not being a keeper/possibility.

Is there a way to force Windows & the MS Surface tablet to keep the midi (or USB) driver awake (prevent the driver from sleeping)? Is there a registry or other setting that controls the midi driver sleep? Or is there code I can add to my app that would force the midi driver to stay awake?

Thanks!

Comment: What are those other issues?

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround...I noticed that the MS Surface tablet appeared to keep the Midi driver fully awake as long as any sound was playing on the device so I wrote some code (leveraging NAudio) to play "silent sound" any time I want/need to keep the midi driver awake.

See NAudio.Wave.SilenceProvider if you need a similar solution.

NAudio has proven to be an extremely helpful tool for me in dealing with audio and midi in MS Windows. Many thanks to Mark Heath!